# Cassandra insert fails

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-enterprise, datastax, datastax-java-driver

We're experiencing problems with writing data in cassandra table.

The flow is following.. we delete all records from `XXX` with some primary key. 
Then inserting new ones in loop.

```
execute("DELETE FROM XXX WHERE key = {SOME_UUID}");

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    execute("INSERT INTO XXX (key, field1, field2) VALUES ({SOME UUID},'field1','field2')";
}
```

The result: Sometimes not all rows are inserted into the table. After querying the table we see that not all rows were inserted.

The environment we have:

We use DataStax Enterprise Edition (4.5.2). Cassandra 2.0.10.
The datacenter has 4 nodes and the keyspace we work on has `replication_factor` set to 3.
The queries `CONSISTENCY_LEVEL` is set to `LOCAL_QUORUM`.

The java driver is data stax enterprise 2.1.1

Thanks in advance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the logs show anything (tried running in dbug)?

Comment: nothing suspicious in logs. No exceptions. None of queries are marked as failed...

Comment: Try dialing your write consistency down to `ONE` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Check your cassandra db 's system time. It could be off by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in your example that SOME_UUID is the same for the delete and the insert.

It's probably a race condition between the delete (tombstone) and the new inserts being propagated to all the nodes (per your replication factor). If the delete and insert are marked with the same timestamp, the delete will win. You may have a case where on some nodes the delete wins, and on others the insert wins.

You could try lowering RF to 1, as @BryceAtNetwork23 suggested.

Another test would be to insert a delay (like 500ms) in your sample code between the delete and the insert for loop. That would give time for the delete to propagate before the inserts come through.

Depending on your data model, the best solution here might be to avoid the need for the deletes.

Comment: Well we'v tried with CL = 1. The RF of keyspace was 2 and the CL = 1. And we experienced same problem. So we switched to RF=3 CL=QUORUM. We tried to put some delay between delete and inserts and look like that helps...So can we suppose that it's normal to see such a behaviour for Cassandra?

Comment: @Daa While I don't believe that should really be considered "normal" behavior, I can tell you that frequently deleting data from a table is considered an anti-pattern for Cassandra.  Maybe there's a way for you to artificially expire the row (instead of deleting it) and just add a new one?

Comment: Regarding the queries having the same timestamp: note that in the upcoming version 2.1.2 of the driver, and provided you use Cassandra >= 2.1.0, the timestamps will be generated client-side so that should not happen anymore.